# ElementTree attrib is empty

Tags: python, xml, parsing, python-3.x

I have XML document.

```
<idmclient>
    <version build="" major="1" minor="1" sprint="15" />  
</idmclient>
```

And python code

```
  import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse, Element, SubElement, ElementTree
import sys
file = "C://inetpub//idmclient//version.xml";
tree = parse(file)
elem = tree.getroot()
version = SubElement(elem, "version")
print (version.attrib)
```

it's print {}. But i have 4 attributes. After I want to write in build any number and save, but now, when i write and save it looks like this

```
  <idmclient>
    <version build="" major="1" minor="1" sprint="15" />
<version build="666" /></idmclient>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find()` instead to get an element by it's name. Then you can use `set()` to update `build` attribute value like so :

```
.....
version = elem.find('version')
version.set('build', '666')

print(version.attrib)
# output :
# {'major': '1', 'sprint': '15', 'minor': '1', 'build': '666'}
```